# Google charts issue driving me nuts

Tags: google-visualization

I'm trying to generate a chart via the following url:

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxl=0:|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun&chxt=x&chbh=a,6,10&chs=320x225&cht=bvg&chco=A2C180&chds=0,95&chd=t:0,0,300,500,0,0,0&chtt=Test

The values are 0 for everything except for Wed and Thu when they are 300 and 500 each. However, the bars in the chart are identically long for wed and thur although wed is representing 300 and thu is representing 500.

I've checked the url format many times and can't find any problem with it. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug with google charts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

The `chds` argument must contain the highest value of the dataset against which all other values are compared, I had copied & pasted my url and had '95' as the `chds` which is why both 300 and 500 showed equally, changing it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a scale problem ; can you print values on the vertical bar, every 10 for example ?